# How to place main method to the top of the screen

Tags: html, css, position

The problem that I am having is that anything that I type in the `<main>` tag starts in the center of the screen, but I need the `<main>`tag for the animation on the navbar. Does anybody know how to fix this?

This is one of my very first 'projects' and am interested if anybody could help me out with making it secure as well. =)

```js
(function() {

  var nav = $('nav'),
      menu = $('nav h1'),
      main = $('main'),
      open = false,
      hover = false;

    menu.on('click', function() {
    open = !open ? true : false;
      nav.toggleClass('menu-active');
      main.toggleClass('menu-active');
      nav.removeClass('menu-hover');
      main.removeClass('menu-hover');
      console.log(open);
  });

    menu.hover( 
      function() {
        if (!open) {
          nav.addClass('menu-hover');
          main.addClass('menu-hover');
        }
      },
      function() {
        nav.removeClass('menu-hover');
        main.removeClass('menu-hover');
      }
    );

})();
```

```css
    div{
     color: white;
    }

    html, body{
 height: 100%;
    }

    *{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   }

    body{
 background: #353441;
 font-family: tahoma;
 line-height: 1.7;
 perspective-origin: 0% 50%;
 perspective: 800px;
   }

   main{
 margin-top: 0;
   }

   nav,main{
 transition: transform 150ms ease-out;
   }

   nav{
 z-index: 100;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 16em;
 background-color: #353441;
 transform: translateX(-16em);
   }

   nav.menu-active{
 transform: translateX(0);
   }
   
   nav.menu-hover{
 transform: translateX(-15em);
   }

   nav h1{
 z-index: 100;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: -65px;
 height: 60px;
 width: 65px;
 line-height: 60px;
 font-size: .8em;
 font-weight: 300;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase; 
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #353441; 
 cursor: pointer;
   }

   nav h1:hover{
 color: white;
   }

   nav ul{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0; 
   }

   nav li{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 1em;
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 color: #9dc6d1;
 line-height: 60px;
 background-color: #353441;
 transition: all .5s ease-in;
   }

   nav li:nth-of-type(2n){
 background-color: #3a3947;
   }

   nav li:hover{
 background: orangered;
 color: white;
   }

   main{
 z-index: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 overflow: hidden; 
   }

   main:after{
 content: '';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, transition, rgba(33,33,45,.5));
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity 150ms ease-out, visibility 0s 150ms;
   }

   main.menu-active{
 border-radius: 0.001px;
 transform: translateX(16em) rotateY(15deg);
   }

   main.menu-active:after{
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
 transition: opacity 150ms ease-out, visibility 0s;
   }

   main.menu-hover{
 border-radius: 0.001px;
 transform: translateX(1em) rotateY(1deg); 
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <!--Navigation Bar-->

  <nav class="menu-activea">
   <h1>---</h1>
   <ul>
    <li>Domov</li>
    <li>Majice</li>
    <li>Puloverji</li>
    <li>Skodelice</li>
    <li>Galerija</li>
    <li>O nas</li>
    <li>Kontakt</li>
   </ul>
  </nav>

  <main>

   <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,           
      sed do eiusmod
   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad                                                     
     minim veniam,
   quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
   consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
   cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
   proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>

  </main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main tag is defined with a display of flex and it's aligning the items to the centre. Remove the css align-items: center for the main tag and everything will be pushed to the top:

```js
(function() {

  var nav = $('nav'),
      menu = $('nav h1'),
      main = $('main'),
      open = false,
      hover = false;

    menu.on('click', function() {
    open = !open ? true : false;
      nav.toggleClass('menu-active');
      main.toggleClass('menu-active');
      nav.removeClass('menu-hover');
      main.removeClass('menu-hover');
      console.log(open);
  });

    menu.hover( 
      function() {
        if (!open) {
          nav.addClass('menu-hover');
          main.addClass('menu-hover');
        }
      },
      function() {
        nav.removeClass('menu-hover');
        main.removeClass('menu-hover');
      }
    );

})();
```

```css
div{
     color: white;
    }

    html, body{
 height: 100%;
    }

    *{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   }

    body{
 background: #353441;
 font-family: tahoma;
 line-height: 1.7;
 perspective-origin: 0% 50%;
 perspective: 800px;
   }

   main{
 margin-top: 0;
   }

   nav,main{
 transition: transform 150ms ease-out;
   }

   nav{
 z-index: 100;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 16em;
 background-color: #353441;
 transform: translateX(-16em);
   }

   nav.menu-active{
 transform: translateX(0);
   }
   
   nav.menu-hover{
 transform: translateX(-15em);
   }

   nav h1{
 z-index: 100;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: -65px;
 height: 60px;
 width: 65px;
 line-height: 60px;
 font-size: .8em;
 font-weight: 300;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase; 
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #353441; 
 cursor: pointer;
   }

   nav h1:hover{
 color: white;
   }

   nav ul{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0; 
   }

   nav li{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 1em;
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 color: #9dc6d1;
 line-height: 60px;
 background-color: #353441;
 transition: all .5s ease-in;
   }

   nav li:nth-of-type(2n){
 background-color: #3a3947;
   }

   nav li:hover{
 background: orangered;
 color: white;
   }

   main{
 z-index: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 display: flex;
 /* align-items: center; */
 overflow: hidden; 
   }

   main:after{
 content: '';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, transition, rgba(33,33,45,.5));
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity 150ms ease-out, visibility 0s 150ms;
   }

   main.menu-active{
 border-radius: 0.001px;
 transform: translateX(16em) rotateY(15deg);
   }

   main.menu-active:after{
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
 transition: opacity 150ms ease-out, visibility 0s;
   }

   main.menu-hover{
 border-radius: 0.001px;
 transform: translateX(1em) rotateY(1deg); 
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <!--Navigation Bar-->

  <nav class="menu-activea">
   <h1>---</h1>
   <ul>
    <li>Domov</li>
    <li>Majice</li>
    <li>Puloverji</li>
    <li>Skodelice</li>
    <li>Galerija</li>
    <li>O nas</li>
    <li>Kontakt</li>
   </ul>
  </nav>

  <main>

   <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,           
      sed do eiusmod
   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad                                                     
     minim veniam,
   quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
   consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
   cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
   proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>

  </main>
```